# Is it possible to create a SYN packet and then trasmit it with the socket send() function?

Tags: c++, sockets

So I am currently writing a C++ program that is a peer-to-peer instant messenger. So when the program starts, it listens for incoming connections on a designated port but also will allow the user to initiate a connection to another host by entering their IP address. Now the socket *connect()* function AFAIK works much like the *send()* function but it transmits a SYN packet until the server responds with an *accept()* or if the server rejects the connection is closed down. So the main question is.......If I create a socket and then call the listen() function, will I get an error if I then call the connect function on the same port? If so, is there a way to create a SYN packet and then call the *send()* function to transmit it to the designated host? This program is a deviation from the client-server model because any host running this program is going to act as both a client AND a server.

Answer (score 2):

A socket can either `listen` or `connect`.  It can't do both.

If you want each host to be both a client and a server then each will need two sockets.

On MacOS X at least, there's a specific error message for what you're trying to do in the `connect(2)` man page:

> `[EOPNOTSUPP]`       Because socket is listening, no connection is allowed.

Comment: On Windows, `connect()` returns `WSAEINVAL` if the socket is already listening.

Comment: In that case Alnitak, is there a way to construct a SYN packet and then use the send() function to transmit the packet??? Keep in mind that no more than 1 TCP/IP socket can use a specific port at one time.

Comment: @MrX I don't understand why you believe this is necessary.  It's completely unclear what problem you think this will solve.

Answer (score 2):

> Now the socket connect() function AFAIK works much like the send() function but it transmits a SYN packet until the server responds with an accept() or if the server rejects the connection is closed down

That's not correct for a start. `connect()` sends a SYN all right, but the ACK reply comes from the peer TCP stack, possibly long before the server application gets anywhere near calling `accept()`. This is because of the listen backlog queue.

So your motivation is already suspect.

> If I create a socket and then call the listen() function, will I get an error if I then call the connect function on the same port?

Yes. You can't do that. You haven't motivated this question, but you don't even need to do that. You have no requirement to use the same local port for an outbound connection that you are listening for inbound connections on.

> is there a way to create a SYN packet and then call the send() function to transmit it to the designated host?

You can send a SYN manually, if you can work out how to create a raw IP socket, but you can't get TCP/IP to recognize it as part of a TCP connection. Again this has nothing to do with whatever your problem is.

I'm not even convinced you *have* a problem actually. All you need is a listening socket, accepted sockets, and sockets for outbound connections, all created in the usual way. No tricks required.

Comment: EJP: For outbound connections, when I call the connect() function there has to be a listening socket on the other end listening on the outgoing port. So the listening port and outgoing connection ports would need to be crossed on their machine. Thanks for your answer though. But I've concluded that TCP/IP is clearly not the right protocol for this application.

Comment: So I've done a bit more homework here and I think that SCTP is the protocol I should use instead.

Comment: @MrX There has to be a peer socket listening at an *incoming* port. None of what you propose gets around that necessity. Neither does SCTP as far as I can see, or port 'crossing' either. I think you just have some major misunderstandings, and you've clearly started designing a solution before you fully understand the problem, whatever it is.

Comment: Perhaps I do. However, if I can do this with TCP/IP sockets then that makes my life a whole lot easier. My confusion was that I thought that outgoing connection ports and incoming listening ports had to be matched up. But now I realize that what I need to do is to use  non-blocking sockets.